# RTX 3060 Ti is booting on occasion

Tags: graphics-card

I just bought a 3060 Ti founders edition and once plugged in everything seemed fine until I started my pc up the next day and the card won’t turn on. I have replaced it with my old 1660 super which works perfectly which has caused me confusion why my new card isn’t working. I have had this problem for a couple months now and I try it again once every couple weeks and it works when I plug it back in until I turn my pc off. Any help would be appreciated and I will put the rest of my specs here.

- CPU - Intel 9700kf
- Motherboard - MSI Z390 gaming edge ac
- Ram - Corsair Vengeance 2x8gb 3200MHz
- Storage - Sabrent 1Tb mvme ssd + 4 hdd

Comment: Your new GPU requires _double_ the power. Can your PSU provide that?

Comment: That was my first thought. The 30 series cards are *hungry* for power. Most upgrades from older cards or lower ones absolutely need a new PSU as well.

Comment: I have a 650W Corsair Bronze PSU, sorry I forgot to mention it. In that case do you think that undervolting the card will sort my problem? That’s if I can get it working for the day again.